# Understanding: floor((row_number() over (ORDER BY CHDR.UNIQUE_NUMBER ASC)-1)/100)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have no idea what this query does and how it is calculated.

Could someone take a look

```
floor((row_number() over (ORDER BY CHDR.UNIQUE_NUMBER ASC)-1)/100)
```

Comment: Please refer to official documentation. T-SQL is very well documented and you should have no problem understanding what this does after reading the relevant documents.

Answer (score 3):

Floor - largest integer value that is smaller than or equal to a number.
For example floor of 2.4 is 2

ROW_NUMBER() is a windows function which assigns a row number for each row according to a condition, in your case  `CHDR.UNIQUE_NUMBER ASC` will get the Ascending order of the column CHDR.UNIQUE.

So to put it all together this statement will get the row number for each row after ordering by CHDR.UNIQUE then will substract 1 and divide it by 100 and gets the smaller integer value closer to it.

Comment: Note : the `floor()` is redundant here and does not have any effect as `row_number()` returns integer value

Comment: @Squirrel `floor` is applied after that `row_number` has been divided by 100...

Comment: Hi@AakashM what @squirrel mentioned was correct when we divide an integer by 100 the value will still remain integer due to precision.